# Recurly hosted payment pages success response

Tags: recurly

i was able to use recurly with Hosted payment pages. These hosted pages can a success redirect URL which can be like

www.example.com/success?account={{account_code}}&planc_code={{plan_code}}

what is code for getting transaction ID in the success redirect URL so that i can query the api in the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transaction UUID cannot be returned in the success URL. Please either use webhooks or an API query to get this more detailed information.

Comment: How can we do API query without any related information for particular transaction.

Comment: the success URL will give you the account_code, which you can use to get a list of transactions associated with that account.